# Convert a multi dimensional array into an array of lower dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

Given a 2-dimensional array `A`, there are at least two natural ways to convert it into an array of arrays:

- Array of columns of A

  ```
  [A[:,j] for j in 1:size(A,2)]
  ```
- Array of rows of A

  ```
  [A[i,:] for i in 1:size(A,1)]
  ```

My questions are:

1. Is there an easier way to achieve the above? ("easier" might mean shorter or without comprehensions)
2. Is there a general way to easily convert n-dimensional arrays into arrays of dimension n-1 along any given dimension? (The case above is the special case for n=2).

Note: A somewhat similar question was already asked, but with a different focus:

[Calling a C function from Julia and passing a 2D array as a pointer of pointers as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003174/calling-a-c-function-from-julia-and-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-pointer-of-pointers/33153086#33153086)

Comment: In Julia 0.7 you can do e.g. `selectdim.([x], 2, axes(x, 2))` which is useful when you have a multidimensional array (so no need to use `:`). If you do not want a view but a copy wrap it in `copy` i.e. `copy.(selectdim.([x], 2, axes(x, 2)))`. In Julia 0.6 you have `slicedim` that does the same (with copy behavior). I am not sure if you would call this shorter :).

Comment: Honestly I like the comprehensions here...

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thanks for mentioning `slicedim` and `selectdim`. They seem more suitable when it is not possible to hardcode the dimension.

Comment: If you don't want do copy data around you can reinterpret your array as Array{SVector{}}. But this only works if you use the last dimensions for splitting and don't require write access.